# Returning the dialog box information

Tags: java

Trying to get the information to return, the information is not printing from the system.out.print ln() statement.  I do not know how to change it to print out the information using the method.

```
package TESTCODe;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TESTCODe {
private static Component frame;
private static Icon icon;
public static void main(String[] args) {
int selection=0;
    int menu = read_menu();
    while(selection!=3)
    {       if(selection==1)
        {   System.out.println("random");           }
    else
        if(selection==2)
            {System.out.println("WH form");             }
        menu=read_menu();
    }           System.out.println("Exiting");  
 System.exit(0);
  } public static int read_menu()
{       int selection=0;
    Object[] possibilities = {"test1", "test2", "Exit"};
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        frame,"Choose a form",
                "Form",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,icon,
                        possibilities,"test1");

if(s.equals("test1"))
    {           selection=Integer.parseInt(s);
        selection=1;
    }
    else
        if(s.equals("Wh"))
        {               selection=Integer.parseInt(s);
            selection=2;
        }
        else
            if(s.equals("Exit"))
            {                   selection=Integer.parseInt(s);
                selection=3;
            }return selection;
    }
 }
```

Any help is much appreicated. thank you

Comment: Clean up your indentation! You check if s is the string "Air Conditioning" and then if it is, you try to parse that as an int? Also in your main you set `selection = 0`, then check whether its value is 1 or 2 without ever changing its value from zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
int menu = read_menu();
```

With :

```
selection = read_menu();
```

Reason: You are printing the value of "selection", but you have assigned the returning int from read_menu() function to "menu". Hence you need to do the above replacement.

Remove the following line from your main method:

```
menu=read_menu();
```

Reason: you are not using the "menu" variable for your if...else loop nor for printing using System.out.println, so why use it?

And remove all

```
selection=Integer.parseInt(s);
```

lines from read_menu() function.

Reason: You are setting selection to an int value in the next step, so this line is useless, and also you are trying to convert a string to an int, which could cause an error.

This way your code should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help this helped me a lot.